# How to forcefully end an iteration of a for-loop (without stopping the for-loop)?

Tags: for-loop, p5.js

This may be a stupid question, but here goes. Is there a way to forcefully end an iteration of a for-loop and ignore all other conditional statements within the loop, and move onto the next iteration?

I'm trying to make a tool where whenever a user types a letter, it's printed to the canvas.

I'm using a for loop to do this, with each iteration making the next letter move to the right each time.

Inside the for-loop includes the conditional statements for typing the letter:

```javascript
function draw(){
}
function keyPressed(){
    for(i=0; i<100; i++){
        if(keyCode == 65){
            text("a", 60 + i*10, 60)
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

and so on, and so forth. However, this would only work if after each letter it moved onto the next iteration (otherwise the letters would be printed in the same place due to 'i' not increasing, making it unreadable).

Using 'return' at the end of each condition statement doesn't work for me as 'return' ends the entire for-loop, whereas I just want to end that specific iteration.

All help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about it as a while loop instead? So that you register input while a  key is pressed, instead of a for-loop that runs a finite amount of times?

Comment: @IncrediblePony Thank you for the response. I did actually think of using a while loop, but the main problem remained. I don't have an issue with only being able to type a finite amount of words (100). I just need to be able to forcefully jump to the next iteration. Thank you regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `continue` keyword. Here's an example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp):

```javascript
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 3) { continue; }
  text += "The number is " + i + "<br>";
}
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_continue) is a linke to try the code yourself.

But taking a step back, this feels like a flawed design. If you want to get the key they user pressed, you don't have to use a bunch of `if` statements. You can just use the `key` variable. From the [P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/key):

```javascript
function setup() {
  fill(245, 123, 158);
  textSize(50);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  text(key, 33, 65); // Display last key pressed.
}
```

Even if that won't work for some reason (if you want to display something for the arrow keys, for example), there are probably better ways to solve this problem than a bunch of `if` statements in a `for` loop. For example you could create a mapping from `keyCode` to the string you want to display, and then call that mapping. Something like:

```javascript
var m = new Map()
m.set(65, 'a');
m.set(66, 'b');
//..

function keyPressed(){
  text(m.get(keyCode), 50, 50);
}
```